# Who should be responsible for A/B testing and conversion optimization?

Tags: usability-testing, ab-testing, optimisation

Currently, I'm wearing many hats, but looking to expand our team and eventually dedicate someone to running A/B, MVT and conversion optimizations for us.

With companies where even minor % improvements can yield huge profit increases, who are the people responsible for **managing** the conversion optimization, including online experiments? What are their roles, so I can Google for some job descriptions and more info?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for some kind of marketing person to manage your marketing campaigns. Titles of "copywriter" and "SEO specialist" also come to mind.

Comment: Marketing department?

Comment: This type of role will typically fall under the title of "Web Analyst". Although I've also seen it as "Digital Marketing analyst", and "Online Marketing Strategist".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although all of the above could be part of a UX designers role if you are focused purely on analytics and conversions then potential roles titles would probably include the word **analyst** and be prepended by: **Business/web/marketing/digital**. http://www.clickz.com/clickz/column/1712911/becoming-experienced-invaluable-web-analyst

The other angle to approach it from would be something like **digital marketing**. Or you could even combine them together like: http://www.freshegg.com/assets/pdf/digital_marketing_analyst.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The most common job title for the role you are looking to fill would be Conversion Optimization Strategist.  This differentiates the position from an Analyst which would include analyzing, setting up and maintaining your overall Google Analytics account.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective people for running A/B testing are those with strong all-round UX skills. Afterall it's just another tool to use for optimising your website and improving the user experience. I'd recommend that they are also fairly analytical so they understand conversion rates and uplift etc.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't think that there should *a* person who is responsible. A/B testing is a useful tool in many different contexts. I've seen people from the business side, from marketing, from sales, from development, from ux all want/need to run A/B tests.

There needs to be coordination certainly. There might need to be mechanisms and some dedicated resources to help implement them. But I think deciding that A/B testing belongs to, for example, just marketing is a mistake.

Comment: I disagree. It is extremely important to put ownership of conversion rate optimization on a person or a team of people dedicated to this subject. Many large enterprise brands have *teams* dedicated to testing. The last thing you want is a bunch different people running tests on the same site.

Comment: I agree that having random folk doing random tests is a bad idea. I disagree that having a single individual/team be solely responsible is the only way to stop that happening.